# Can I return and include file in a function for creating shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a shortcode that will return an bunch of HTML elements. In the beginning it was fine to do it this way:

```
add_shortcode( 'about_us', 'shortcode_about' );
function shortcode_about() {
    return "<div>Some content here.</div>";
}
```

But now I have to add a lot of content, which I think wouldn't look good as my `functions.php` will be filled with a lot of this. I was wondering if I can just put it in an external file and include it.

I hoped something like this would work:

```
add_shortcode( 'about_us', 'shortcode_about' );
function shortcode_about() {
    return include 'about-us.php';
}
```

But of course, it didn't. Any ideas on how to do this properly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
add_shortcode( 'about_us', 'shortcode_about' );

function shortcode_about()
{
    // Get absolute path to file.
    $file = locate_template('my-file.php');

    // Check if file is found.
    if ($file) {
        // Return file contents.
        ob_start();
        include $file;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
add_shortcode( 'about_us', 'shortcode_about' );

function shortcode_about()
{
   ob_start();
    require_once('about-us.php');
    $data = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $data;
}
```

code in about-us.php

```
<div>Some content here.</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
add_shortcode( 'about_us', 'shortcode_about' );
function add_shortcode()
{

    ob_start();
        include( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/include.php' );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and in **include.php**

```
<h1>Test Content</h1>
<p>This is the data</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Is `include( dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/include.php' );` necessary instead of just `include 'include.php';`? The two files are in the same directory.