# How to remove unwanted number after custom wordpress shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have two file "my-plugin.php" and "test.view.php" in root of custom plugin.  Content of "my-plugin.php" is:

```
    /*
  Plugin Name: test
  Plugin URI: test.com
  Description: test
  Version: 1.0
  Author: test
  Author URI: test
  License: GPLv2+
  Text Domain: conference
*/
class Test{
    function __construct() {
        add_shortcode('testShortCode' , array( $this, 'shortCode'));
    }
    function shortCode() {
        return include 'test.view.php';
    }
}
new Test();
```

And "test.view.php" is:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

I put [testShortCode] in a page but after print Test i see a "1" after it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it as follows:

```
function shortCode() {
    ob_start();
    require_once('test.view.php');
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $data;
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805702/1082008

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> Handling Returns: *include* returns FALSE on failure and raises a
>   warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file,
>   return *1*.

So, to get rid of the *1* you're seeing, you either change `test.view.php` contents to:

```
return "<h1>Test</h1>";
```

... or you change your `shortCode()` function to:

```
function shortCode() {
    include 'test.view.php';
}
```